# Im looking for a way to make my discord bot inline reply some specific user. My current bot only sends messages but does not inline replies

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, message

So my bot work in such way that it uses a .txt document in which the whole conversation its included, its made in such way that sends messages every minute from the list until its over. The thing I want to do, is to make it reply to an especific user (this user is another account of mine) that its also running as a bot and has the other part of the conversation. What I want is to make both bots talk to each other with the conversations I made. So basically I just need to find a way so that it tags or inline replies the other bot.

This is the code, as you can see its very simple, it just sends messages from "cloodle1.txt" every 62 seconds.

```
import requests
import pyautogui
import time 

f = open("cloodle1.txt", "r")
time.sleep(2)
for words in f:
    payload ={  'content' : (words)
    }
    
    header = {
    'authorization': 'DISCORD TOKEN'}


    r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/DISCORD CHANNEL ID/messages", 
                  data=payload, headers=header)
    time.sleep(62)
```

How can I make it tag some specific person everytime it sends a message?
Sorry Im kinda new programming stuff.

Comment: what specific person? do you have their IDs? how do you determine what user to ping?

Comment: Yes, I have the ID and token of the other user I want to reply to. I know the exact user I want to reply too

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `message_reference` key to your `payload` dict.
Something like this:

```py
payload = {
    'content': words,
    'message_reference': {
        'message_id': MESSAGE_ID # This is a variable containing the id of the message you want to reply to.
    }
}
```

There are a few other options, including one that sends your message as a normal message if the message you are trying to reply to is gone.

Resources:

- [Discord API Create Message Endpoint Documentation (`POST /channels/{channel.id}/messages`)](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)
- [Discord API Message Reference Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-reference-object-message-reference-structure)